# nameref doesn't show in main text when choosing textcolor = white for table caption

Tags: pdftex, color, nameref

I have a table that has a red background and using white text for the caption comes up better than black. This is done by using:

```
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=csuOrange,title= \caption{
    \textcolor{white}{Qualitative feedback from students in Bioethics courses.
    }\label{table_evaluation_bioethics}}]
```

However, trying to use `\nameref{}` in the main text to reference the table doesn't show up because the text is white. I have tried several things to rectify this, but to no avail. One example being:

```
\textcolor{black}{\nameref{table_evaluation_bioethics}}
```

I cannot find anything online that references a similar problem. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I could use a simple numbered `\ref{}` instead and that works, but I would prefer the table name instead.

EDIT:

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the behavior:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb, amstext, amsmath, epstopdf, booktabs, verbatim, gensymb, geometry, appendix, natbib, lmodern}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\definecolor{csuOrange}{RGB}{153,0,76}

\begin{document}
    
    This is an example of using ref: see Table~\ref{table_evaluation_bioethics}.
    
    This is an example of using nameref: see \nameref{table_evaluation_bioethics}.
    
    The problem is the white text color for the caption.

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=csuOrange,title= \caption{
            \textcolor{white}{Qualitative feedback from students in Bioethics courses.}\label{table_evaluation_bioethics}}]
        
        \taburulecolor{csuOrange}
        \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{c | X  | l}
            
            \toprule
            Course & Students' Feedback &  \\
            %%%%%%%%%%%Spring 2020%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \midrule
            %
            \multirow{11}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Section D}}
            &
            
            \blindtext
            
            & \multirow{11}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Spring 2018}}
            \\
            \midrule
            
            \multirow{11}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Section E}}
            &
            
            \blindtext
            
            & \multirow{11}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Fall 2018}}
            \\
            \bottomrule
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \end{xltabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippets be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: unrelated but do not use the tabu package, it is broken and unmaintained.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The `\caption` itself had to be moved within the `\textcolor` command for it to not affect the `\hyperref`:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=csuOrange,title= \textcolor{white}{\caption{
        Qualitative feedback from students in Bioethics courses.}\label{table_evaluation_bioethics}}]
```